# How array pointer works in threads?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm new to pthreads and trying to understand it. I wrote a program that creates new thread, which creates one more thread... and so on till threads_count != 10; I want to pass 2 parameters to the thread as array. When i call it from main - it works. When i call it inside of function I become something like

```
Sleeping for 4 sec before thread creation
Sleeping for 32767 sec before thread creation
Sleeping for 28762 sec before thread creation
Sleeping for 28762 sec before thread creation
Sleeping for 28762 sec before thread creation
Sleeping for 28762 sec before thread creation
```

Am I passing arguments inside of function to the new thread wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_THREADS 10 

int threads_count = 0;



void* SpawnTwoThreads(void *args) {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;  

    int* thread_args = (int*)args;
    printf("Sleeping for %d sec before thread creation\n", thread_args[1]);
    sleep(5); 
    if(threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
        threads_count++;
        thread_args[1] = rand() % 10;
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &thread_args);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t1;
    int t1_wait_time;

    srand(time(NULL));

    int start_args[2];
    start_args[0] = 0;
    start_args[1] = rand() % 10;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &start_args);

    printf("In main: waiting for all threads to complete\n");
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("Overall waittime is %d\n", wait_time_overall);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You're passing a pointer to a local variable, which becomes invalid when the function returns.

Comment: But if I make it to global variable, then I become segmentation fault

Comment: All your `thread_args` are copies of the same pointer that came from `main()`, so you're overwriting `start_args[1]` each time. You should also use a mutex around the increment of `threads_count`.

Comment: Yes, i know, that I'm overwriting it each time. I did array as global variable(outside of main) then passed it in main to the first thread as parameter. Inside of function I've locked counter with mutex. But I'm becoming segmentation fault.

Comment: you are trying to modify the value of the array concurrently in threads. It probably does not matter much in this (random) case, but you should use mutexes to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In the `pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &thread_args);` inside `SpanTwoThreads()` you're passing a double pointer, while you should just use `thread_args` as last argument (as it's already a pointer). In the `main()` function you don't see this issue as `start_args` is declared as an array, so putting an & symbol in front of it will be the same as just using the name of the array itself.